# jQuery dom ready and run javascript when library jquery loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I do not want to wait until DOM ready with `$(document).ready(function()`. So, how to execute my inline and not inline javascript (jQuery) code when jQuery library 100% downloaded and executed? Seems it's not safe to write code without some wrapper like `$(document).ready(function()`, because browser can try to execute code while `jQuery library not ready`.

Also I have the question about the situation with `$(document).ready(function()` when I have some external javascripts like `addthis` on the page. Am I right that DOM is NOT ready until `addthis` javascript not loaded?

The problem is that I am already seen some links on the page and I need to add to them some parameters with jQuery, before user will click on the link, but user click before DOM ready and parameter losses.

Thanks.

Comment: script are loaded synchronously if you don't set specific attribute as `defer`. So once you include jQuery, you can use it.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks. what is about `bind` event. If I want to bind for some already ready elements and then `rebind` when DOM is ready? Is it safe to can `bind` two times? Will jQuery forget about first binding to the same element?

Comment: you should then delegate event to closest static container. You can use .on() for that, e.g: `$(document.body).on('click', '.myClass', handler);` see in the DOC